# Python amend content of CSV and resave

Tags: python, csv

Require the program to search for a row then adjust a particular element of the `CSV` before re-saving.

Any help appreciated!

```
import csv
import os
username=input('Enter username: ')
with open ('user.csv', 'r') as user:
    reader=csv.reader(user, delimiter=',')
    print(reader)

with open ('newuser.csv', 'w') as newdetail:
    writer=csv.writer(newdetail, delimiter=',')
    for colomn in reader:
        if username in coloum[1]:
            print('User found! \n')
            print('UserID: '+colomn[0])
            print('Username: '+colomn[1])
            print('Interest: '+colomn[2])
            change = (column[2])
            change = input("What is your new interest?")
            print(colomn[2]+' has been changed to ', change)
        writer.writerow(colomn)
os.remove('user.csv')
os.rename('newuser.csv', 'user.csv')
```

The current error is:

> ```
> dir/ line 10, in <module>
>     for colomn in reader:
> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
> ```

Much appreciated, this is where I am up to now. Currently only prints the single line that's being edited and not all of the other movies that have not been adjusted.

```
import csv
import os
new = []
username=input('Enter movie: ')
with open ('movies.csv', 'r') as user:
    reader=csv.reader(user, delimiter=',')
    #print(reader)

    with open ('newmovies.csv', 'w') as newdetail:
        writer=csv.writer(newdetail, delimiter=',')
        for colomn in reader:
            if username in colomn[1]:
                print('Movie found!')
                print('MovieID: '+colomn[0])
                print('Movie name: '+colomn[1])
                print('Interest: '+colomn[2])
        choice = input("what is your new interest?")
        print('Interest has been changed to ', choice)
        new = [(colomn[0]),(colomn[1]),(choice)]
        writer.writerow(new)
os.remove('movies.csv')
os.rename('newmovies.csv', 'movies.csv')
```

Comment: Why on earth did you introduce errors in the code given by Dimgold? The answer is still in his answer and still caused by *indentation* errors.

Comment: The current solution does change the data where required although all of the other content is deleted which is frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

`reader` object is not containing the data, but only has a direct access to the file. Once you close the `user.csv` file (when exiting from `with` scope) the `reader` is no more useful.

Try to put the second `with` inside the 1st scope:

```
with open ('user.csv', 'r') as user:
    reader=csv.reader(user, delimiter=',')
    print(reader)
    with open ('newuser.csv', 'w') as newdetail:
        writer=csv.writer(newdetail, delimiter=',')
        for colomn in reader:
            if username in colomn[1]:
                print('User found! \n')
                print('UserID: '+colomn[0])
                print('Username: '+colomn[1])
                print('Interest: '+colomn[2])
                change = (column[2])
                change = input("What is your new interest?")
                print(colomn[2]+' has been changed to ', change)
            writer.writerow(colomn)
```

P.S. - fix the 11th line as well - `colomn` instead of `coloum`

Comment: Much appreciated, this is where I am up to now. Currently only prints the single line that's being edited and not all of the other movies that have not been adjusted.